# MongoDB grouping on both a date and text fields

Tags: mongodb, date, aggregation-framework

I have been using MongoDb for a while now and think its great.  I have the following Activity object.

```
[ Activity ]
"_id"       : ObjectId("518a6c18e4b079d18de65b6e"),
"userUrl"   : "http://news.bbc.co.uk",
"userAddress"   : "1.2.3.4",
"requestTime"   : ISODate("2013-05-08T15:15:35.780Z"),
"status"    : "success"
```

NOTE, there are about 5 different values for the status field e.g. "error", "unavailable", etc

So I'm at the stage now of doing high level reporting on load but having problems with a grouping function.  For example, if I insert the following test data: -

```
db.activity.insert({"userUrl": "http://news.bbc.co.uk", "userAddress" : "1.2.3.4", "requestTime" : new Date('Jan 01, 2013'), "status": "success"})
db.activity.insert({"userUrl": "http://news.bbc.co.uk", "userAddress" : "1.2.3.4", "requestTime" : new Date('Jan 01, 2013'), "status": "success"})
db.activity.insert({"userUrl": "http://news.bbc.co.uk", "userAddress" : "1.2.3.4", "requestTime" : new Date('Jan 01, 2013'), "status": "error"})
db.activity.insert({"userUrl": "http://news.bbc.co.uk", "userAddress" : "1.2.3.4", "requestTime" : new Date('Jan 01, 2013'), "status": "unavailable"})
db.activity.insert({"userUrl": "http://news.bbc.co.uk", "userAddress" : "1.2.3.4", "requestTime" : new Date('Jan 02, 2013'), "status": "success"})
db.activity.insert({"userUrl": "http://news.bbc.co.uk", "userAddress" : "1.2.3.4", "requestTime" : new Date('Jan 02, 2013'), "status": "error"})
db.activity.insert({"userUrl": "http://news.bbc.co.uk", "userAddress" : "1.2.3.4", "requestTime" : new Date('Jan 02, 2013'), "status": "error"})
db.activity.insert({"userUrl": "http://news.bbc.co.uk", "userAddress" : "1.2.3.4", "requestTime" : new Date('Jan 02, 2013'), "status": "unavailable"})
db.activity.insert({"userUrl": "http://news.bbc.co.uk", "userAddress" : "1.2.3.4", "requestTime" : new Date('Jan 02, 2013'), "status": "unavailable"})
```

... and I run this function ...

```
db.activity.group(
{
    $keyf : function(doc) {
        return { "date" : doc.requestTime.getDate() + "/" + doc.requestTime.getMonth() + "/" + doc.requestTime.getFullYear()};
    },
    initial: { count:0 },
    reduce: function(obj, prev) { prev.count++; }
})
```

... I get this result ...

```
[
    {
        "date" : "1/0/2013",
        "count" : 4
    }, 
    {
        "date" : "2/0/2013",
        "count" : 5
    }
]
```

Which works really nicely for grouping just on a date.  **My question is, how would I group on the date (by day) on the status?**  E.g. to get something like this would be ideal: -

```
[
    {
        "date" : "1/0/2013",
        "success" : 2,
        "error": 1,
        "unavailable": 1
    },                   
    },
    {
        "date" : "2/0/2013",
        "success" : 1,
        "error": 2,
        "unavailable": 2
    }
]
```

... or ...

```
[
    {
        "date" : "1/0/2013",
        status: [
            "success" : 2,
            "error": 1,
            "unavailable": 1
        ]
    },                   
    },
    {
        "date" : "2/0/2013",
        status: [
            "success" : 1,
            "error": 2,
            "unavailable": 2
        ]   
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is nicely possible with the Aggregation Framework as long as you have a select set of values as you need to hard code them. In general, it is not possible to promote values to keys.

Here goes the A/F invocation:

```
db.activity.aggregate(
    { $group: {
        _id: { date: '$requestTime' },
        success : {
            $sum: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ 'success', '$status' ] } , 1, 0 ] }
        },
        error : {
            $sum: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ 'error', '$status' ] } , 1, 0 ] }
        },
        unavailable : {
            $sum: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ 'unavailable', '$status' ] } , 1, 0 ] }
        }
    } }
);
```

Which outputs:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : {
                "date" : ISODate("2013-01-02T00:00:00Z")
            },
            "success" : 1,
            "error" : 2,
            "unavailable" : 2
        },
        {
            "_id" : {
                "date" : ISODate("2013-01-01T00:00:00Z")
            },
            "success" : 2,
            "error" : 1,
            "unavailable" : 1
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer!!! Note I had add a curly bracket to the end of $sum in unavailable for it to work.

`$sum: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ 'unavailable', '$status' ] } , 1, 0 ] }`

Comment: I've fixed the typo! (Also, it is common that if you think an answer answered your question, you accept that answer).

Comment: Done. First time using stackoverflow - will try and answer a few questions myself now ... :-)